# Grant access to CloudFront Website without an API via Auth0

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect, amazon-cloudfront, auth0

I have a website that provides specific functionality via javascript that should not be available to the entire internet. The functionality is based on in-browser code and does not require an API.

I would like to deploy the website via AWS CDK and Auth0. Specifically, the website is to be stored in an S3 bucket, which is delivered via CloudFront. Authentication is done via Lambda@Edge, which talks to Auth0. Therefore there is no login page or similar but only an index.html. If a user calls the page, the viewer request of the CloudFront distribution is directly forwarded to the Lambda@Edge function, which checks authentication etc.

Here is an example I used as a guide: https://matt.martz.codes/protect-a-static-site-with-auth0-using-lambdaedge-and-cloudfront

However, I am still not sure if this is really the best way:

1. In the example, the id_token is used for verification. Is that
   correct, or do I rather need the access_token. I know the general
   differences: id_token = authentication, access_token =
   authorization. It follows that the access_token should be used. But:
   ID Tokens should never be used to obtain direct access to APIs or to
   make authorization decisions. And since I don't have an API, I can't
   actually use an access_token, right? What would be the right
   approach here?
2. Is the authorization code flow the right one?
3. Should I use PKCE additionally?

P. S. Yes, I know that this approach does not provide complete security. It does not prevent an authorized user from logging in, downloading the site and then providing it themselves. This risk is known and accepted.

Comment: You are aware when you do a OIDC connect flow you need to use a client secret to validate the client to be able obtain the access token. sharing this client secret somewhere in your browser code is really a bad idea.

Adding PKCE to OIDC will not improve the security as you already shared the keys to the kingdom by sharing the client secret. Most OIDC providers try to prevent these flow out of the box for good reason.

Comment: Hmm, and how do you deal with it in a use case like this one? Or is there no good way to implement a solution like that? I am not sure if this is really a problem. The validation is done via the Lambda@Edge and secrets are stored and validated in the AWS Secrets Manager. These secrets shouldn't be publicly accessable...